# automake undefined reference

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++

I have a problem on linking static libraries..

I have checked and proceeded some methods to solve it, like.. reordering libraries or using some options..

However, All what I've done didn't work..

--
First of all, I'm quite sure it is from link error because I have checked the .a file by nm command and there was specific functions shown in error log.

So, I linked static library like below..

> LOCAL_LINK_STATIC_LIBS := \
>          -I$(libdir)/libmicrohttpd.a\
>          -I$(libdir)/libcryptopp.a\
>          ...
>
> myprog_LDFLAGS = -lstdc++ -g -ldl -lpthread @GLIB_CFLAGS@ $(LOCAL_LINK_STATIC_LIBS)

Is there other way to solve it? I really need your feedback..
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You must only supply the name with the `-l` option, e.g. `-lmicrohttpd`. The linker will add "lib" and ".a" or ".so". Use the `-L` option to set the search path for the libraries, e.g. `-L$(libdir)`.

Also try using `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`. `-lpthread` only links the pthread library whereas `-pthread` will do some additional work.

Comment: I might guess that you were pointing "-l" in "-I$(libdir)/libmicrohttpd.a". It is not 'l' but 'i', which is include option.

Comment: There are two options I can link a library to execution file. 
[   -L$(PATH) -lmicrohttpd   ] or [   -I(i)$(PATH)/libmicrohttpd.a   ], but last method is not working and that is a problem.

Comment: `-I` is used to set the search path for C/C++ header files, not for linking libraries.

Comment: Ah... mistake.. Thanks a lot. I'm going to try your resolution.
Really appreciate it.